# JQuery .Load(), does it cache the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache

Currently working on a simple text adventure game that relies heavily on .load() to pull in content from a document which stores all the games content.

Currently I have it retrieving pieces of the file based on ID (i.e level 201 will pull the container with the id 201 and pull the content from within). I am going for a mobile first approach and expect a decent share of the users to be on mobile so I am trying to cut down on data usage.

I was trying to find online a google chrome extension or some other tool that acts as a listener and measures data usage as I navigate the site but sadly I can't find one. My hope is understanding the .load() function will let me cut down on data usage. if .load() is pulling this singular document and grabbing only a piece of it, does it continually download the file or does it cache the file?

**For example is this occurring:**

> First .load() request of document - downloads 12kb file and pulls only a piece of it onto the screen.
>
> Action occurs and another .load() request from the same document is made. Again the 12kb file is downloaded and another piece is pulled.

**Or is this occurring:**

> First .load() request of document - downloads 12kb file and pulls only a piece of it onto the screen.
>
> Action occurs and another .load() request from the same document is made. The file is already been pulled so it scans the document and a content piece is pulled again.

I tried searching stackoverflow but couldn't find anything that relates to my question (my apologies if I missed one).

Thank you advance for any help with answering this question.

Comment: That depends on the cache headers from the server.

Comment: Did you try it, and see what happens ?

Comment: It will cache as much as entering the address in the address bar will.

Comment: so as long as the site is caching, then the page will be cached on first .load() and the cached copy would be used going forward?

Comment: If you really want to guarantee a cache, I would look into http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp.

Comment: I don't know how to like comments but that app cache is awesome :)

Comment: From a browser perspective I believe it does cache since load() is a shorthand for ajax() which defaults the cache option to true. The actual behaviour of this will vary by browser and web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `jQuery.fn.load` will NOT cache the response. However, the browser might cache it depending on what headers were passed with the response, and possibly the size of the response if the browser being used has limits on the size of the response for caching.

Comment: So then I should split up the document into multiple documents so that only what is needed is downloaded?

Comment: That i don't know, as it would depend on what you are requesting, how often you are requesting it, and how often it changes.

Comment: i'm requesting pieces blocks of HTML at a fairly regular rate. Since its a text adventure game. Every time a player clicks a decision box, content is pulled.

Comment: I would cache them in localstorage rather than relying on the browser to cache it, if they're relatively small (sounds like they are.) Making requests that often can cause things to be slow.